# XALAN API is ignoring SSI include in xsl file when generating HTML file

Tags: java, html, xslt, xalan, ssi

I am using xalan 2.3.1 for generating HTML pages from XSL and XML files.

When I add SSI includes in the XSL file, it is not included in generated HTML files:

Lines ignored by XALAN:

```
<!--#include virtual="/common/include/header_hf.inc" -->

<!--#include virtual="include2.html" -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output a comment (and the SSI syntax is a comment in XML/HTML) with XSLT then you need e.g.

```
<xsl:comment>#include virtual="/common/include/header_hf.inc"</xsl:comment>
```

Comment: Thank u so much for  reply, i tried this but it is not working,it is coming as blank ,i'm suspecting <xsl:template match="/"> tag in my xsl file, this would be the reason for ignoring the comment tag,correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: ok ok,it's my mistake. i got this working.prevoiusly  i saw old generated file..it is working fine now..Thanks again... :)

Comment: @surendra, if your problem has been solved by this answer then accept it so that is will be marked as solved.